# Is there a better way to map an integer to a range of numbers?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to map integers to numbers within range `(1..7)`. `1` through `7` would be mapped to themselves, `8` to `1`, `14` to `7`, and so on.

The obvious candidate to do this is the modulo method `%`. However, `7 % 7` gives `0`, which I do not want.

One can write the following method:

```
def int_map i
  (x = i % 7) == 0 ? 7 : x
end
```

I feel that there should be a better, more succinct way to do this. Is there? And how?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
(1..7).to_a.rotate(i).last
```

Sample program given below:

```
def int_map i
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].rotate(i).last
end

int_map(1)
#=> 1
int_map(7)
#=> 7
int_map(8)
#=> 1
int_map(14)
#=> 7
int_map(15)
#=> 1
```

PS: May be bit inefficient as the value of `i` grows larger, but my tests did not indicate that.  May be Ruby implementation is smart and handles multiple rotations in efficient manner.

Comment: Ruby uses `%` to [calculate the rotation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_3/array.c#L2264-L2268)

Comment: @Stefan  Thanks for the info. That must be it - as my benchmark test did not vary much with varying values of `i`

Answer (score 0):

The result of the method should be:

```
(i - 1) % 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, without using modulo.  The downside is that all this math makes confusing code.

```
i - (i - 1) / 7 * 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Her's another solution.  Quite easy to understand.

```
[7,1,2,3,4,5,6][i % 7]
```

Without specifying the array in full, you can do

```
(1..7).to_a.rotate(-1)[i % 7]
```